# SAX pull parser Android

Tags: android, xml, saxparser

I am parsing a simple XML file through SAX XML parser and show the result in list view. This is sucessfully done. Now I want to do that when the abc tag is closed like below XML file. then below  tag item don't parsed (apple don't add in listview). Can anyone help me. Thanx in advance

```
<abc>
   <employee>
    <name>Android</name>
   </employee>
   <employee>
    <name>Nokia</name>
   </employee>
</abc>
   <employee>
    <name>Apple</name>
   </employee>
```

this is SAXXMLHandler i am using

```
public class SAXXMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    private List<Employee> employees;
    private String tempVal;
    private Employee tempEmp;

    public SAXXMLHandler() {
        employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    }

    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }

    // Event Handlers
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes)
            throws SAXException {
        // reset
        tempVal = "";

        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("employee")) {
            // create a new instance of employee
            tempEmp = new Employee();

        }
    }

    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        tempVal = new String(ch, start, length);
    }

    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {

        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("employee")) {
            // add it to the list
            employees.add(tempEmp);
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
            tempEmp.setName(tempVal);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is this xml your own created?

Comment: yeah loading xml from asset folder

Comment: that's not well formed....I'm giving you the solution with answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain a `boolean` to control that which employee name should add to the list and which should not...as below...

```
public class SAXXMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    private List<Employee> employees;
    private String tempVal;
    private Employee tempEmp;

    private boolean shouldAdd = false;

    public SAXXMLHandler() {
        employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    }

    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }


    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes)
            throws SAXException {

        tempVal = "";

        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("abc")) {

            shouldAdd = true;

        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("employee")) {
            // create a new instance of employee
            tempEmp = new Employee();

        }
    }

    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        tempVal = new String(ch, start, length);
    }

    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {

        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("abc") && shouldAdd == true) {

            shouldAdd = false;

        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("employee") && shouldAdd == true) {
            // add it to the list
            employees.add(tempEmp);
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
            tempEmp.setName(tempVal);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You dont understand what i need. I need to add the item till the abc tag is closed. after that no more item is added in listview. is this possible? or i use other parser for this?